# Why does my PWM Arduino loop not working as intended?

Tags: arduino, motor, pwm

I have a Arduino sketch I am trying to use to control a DC motor using PWM. It seems it it just running the motor as if I the PWM was set to 255 (100%). I intend for my sketch to start the motor slowly (0) and increase every 30ms to 255, then back to 0. However it just seems to run at 100%. Any thoughts? Here is my code.

```
int con = 5;
int amm = 0;
void setup(){
  pinMode(con, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
  analogWrite(con, amm);
  amm = amm + 1;
  if (amm = 255) {
    amm == 0;
  }
  delay(30);
}
```

Am I missing something? I don't code alot in C so maybe I did my loop or variables wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your if statement uses the wrong operators. "=" is assignment and "==" is comparison. I think you have them swapped.

Comment: @freyyr Thanks so much for your suggestion, changing my equal signs did the trick. Such a simple thing, can't believe I missed it. Awesome though to get it working! Thanks!!!!

Comment: In this specific case you can change `int amm = 0;` to `uint8_t amm = 0;` and remove the entire if statement. The `amm` variable will automatically overflow from 255 to 0. Good exercise to read up on how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless im reading this wrong , i would change if(amm = 255)to if(amm == 255)
you need a extra =, and then inside the brackets change amm == 0; to amm = 0;
src : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Awesome! I am not very familiar with C, and I mixed up my equal signs. I feel like such a green horn ;) Thanks so much for pointing out this simple mistake!